# Logs from firebase to Bigquery in the wrong table

Tags: sql, firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I'm using Firebase to register some events from an iOS/Android app and log them into BigQuery. As I understood from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-firebase-analytics-big-query#tables), BigQuery creates a different table each day in order to store the events of the single day.

> Each day, Firebase Analytics creates a new table in the BigQuery dataset corresponding to the app. The tables are named using the pattern app_events_YYYYMMDD and contain the events recorded for the specified day.

However I'm getting some events in a certain day registered in the table of the following day. For example the table app_events_20160727 contains some events from July 26th, the table app_events_20160728 contains some events from July 27th.

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your support

**Sep, 14 Update**

I'll try to better explain the issue through an example: the events recorded in the first part of the day (let's say until 3PM/4PM but I don't see any pattern) are collected in the table of that day, the events of the last part of the day are collected in the table of the following day. 
So, let's take the events of Sep, 12: here below the screenshot of the first and last entries of the tables related to Sep 12 and Sep 13

*First entries of Sep, 13*
[image: First rows of Sep, 13]

*Last entries of Sep, 13*
[image: Last rows of Sep, 13]

*First entries of Sep, 12*
[image: First entries of Sep, 12]

*Last entries of Sep, 12*
[image: Last rows of Sep, 12]

As you can see, the events from Sep, 12 are split into two tables.

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase register the timestamp of when the event was track client side.
This is likely to happen in that scenario:

1. You trigger an event while offline, day N
2. Your user reconnect to internet only the following day, day N+1, (or the day after)
3. Thus Firebase base receive the event of day N, on day N+1.

During day N, firebase will export all the event he received (erver side) on day N. on day N+1 he'll export all the event he received on day N+1, even the one actually track client side on day N, but not sent to server on day N.

I'm unsure the explanation is clear, can you tell if it was clear ?

Comment: Thanks, it is clear but unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case. It happens all the times, every day. Basically the events registered during the morning are collected in the right table while the events registered after 3PM/4PM are displayed in the table of the following day

Comment: 3PM/4PM of which timezone ?
Firebase analytics is likely looking at PMT timezone.

Comment: They might split the table at a weird timezone :/ Not precise in the documentation :/